# Getting data from sqlite when there is no internet connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite

I am using soap service in my project. I am storing data in `sqlite` database. I am unable to write code for getting stored data from `sqlite` without internet. So I want code for getting data when there is no internet connection for user.

Comment: What has database to do with the internet?

Comment: are you search for code and post question ?

Comment: @neha sqlite is use only for fetch data when no internet. so there isn't req of internet for getting data from sqlite

Comment: @neha : Well, you could store bytes of images in db or you have to maintain a download copy of those things. Their is no other way you can do this!

Comment: Anyone know how to create multiple tables and how to insert data into it in sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing data in your sqlite database. But actually there is no connection between database and internet.

You can refer this tutorial for sqlite practice:

- [How to Use SQLite to Manage Data in iOS Apps](http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/)

You can use [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) also which is a wrapper class.